# Erro conectar banco de dados (Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in )

Tags: html, sql, script

estou tendo problemas na conexão do banco de dados do meu site. Acontece o seguinte erro:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()                         in /home/cardgamming/www/configuracao.php:10 Stack trace: #0         /home/cardgamming/www/Painel/inicio.php(2): include() #1 {main} thrown in                 /home/cardgamming/www/configuracao.php on line 10
```

Segue o codigo abaixo:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
    $link_fake = "http://cardgaming.net/"; // SUA URL

    $config['host']     = 'mysql04-farm62.kinghost.net'; // HOST DO BANCO DE                                                 DADOS
    $config['user']     = 'card_add1'; // LOGIN DO BANCO DE DADOS
    $config['pass']     = 'senha123'; // SENHA DO BANCO DE DADOS
    $config['db']       = 'cardgaming'; // NOME DO BANCO DE DADOS

    $selecao =         mysql_connect($config['host'],$config['user'],$config['pass'])or die("erro         dados");
    $conexao = mysql_select_db($config['db'],$selecao);

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'mysql'");
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=mysql');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=mysql');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=mysql');

    $seuemail = "xzedn10@gmail.com"; //CONFIGURE SEU EMAIL
    $assunto_email = "cardgamming"; //ASSUNTO QUE CHEGARA O EMAIL
```

Desde ja obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Funções do tipo mysql_* foram removidas no PHP7.
Você provavelmente está com a versão PHP7.

As funções mysql_* estão obsoletas. A recomendação é utilozar MYSQLI ou PDO.

---

## SOLUÇÕES PARA SEU PROBLEMA

**Solução um (mais recomendada):** utilize PDO ou MYSQLI. O mysqli, por exemplo, tem demasiada semelhança com o mysql:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco_de_dados');
```

**Solução dois (menos recomendada):** mude a versão do seu php. Basta baixar uma versão anterior.